# How to add grandtotal to a crystal reports crosstab report

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a crosstab crystal report (2013).  I have it in a group header, I want a grand report total for each column: `fluidspart`, `shopfee`, `standardlabor`, `standardpart`, `standardservices`, `tirepart`. I'm not sure how to go about doing that part.  Picture can be found here of the report:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TDBbvim.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take one more cross tab in `Report Footer` and place all the fields that you have place in first cross tab and display.

Edit---------------------------------------------------------------------

To get the `prefix`

Assuming your parent database field is `parent`.

Create a formula `@Prefix` write below code and use that formula to group.

```
{Parent}[1]+{Parent}[2]
```

This will pick `RC` and group by the formula

Edit2------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Follow below process to `supress`.

1. Create a formula `@Reset` and place in group header.

   ```
   Shared Numbervar count;
   count:=0
   ```
2. Create one more formula `@Increment` and place in details.. if your customers are in detail

   ```
   Shared Numbervar count;
   count:=count+1;
   ```
3. Now in supress of the `Parent` group footer write below formula.

   ```
   EvaluateAfter({@Increment});
   Shared Numbervar count;

   if (count>1)
   Then true
   Else False
   ```

This will supress the group total

Comment: I'd like to add to this chain, now that I have a grand report total.  I don't have a field that groups my customers by parents, they are distinguished by the letter prefix.  RC4711, the "parent" is RC.  So I have multiple RC customers such as RC4711, RC4742, etc.  How can I group by the prefix and grandtotal on change of the group?

Comment: I have the formula created.  Just don't know how to group it.  not listed in group expert.

Comment: You should be able to see that formula in group expert...it should come by default. Insert group and in dropdown you will have formula

Comment: Awesome.  not sure what the @prefix formula means but you were right it's in group expert.  Works.  Not a big deal but when I have a "parent" that doesn't have multiple customers, the group total is still shown.  Is there a way to suppress it when only one is shown?

Comment: @westbrook check my `Edit2` to supress group total